# Django dynamic form field associated with custom data

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to have access to attributes of passing objects. Is it possible?

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work :(

```
class SearchResultForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, persons, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchResultForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i, person in enumerate(persons):
            self.fields['person_%d' % i] = forms.BooleanField(required=False, custom_data=person)
```

**[EDIT]**

I want be able to do something like this:

```
  <form action="{% url 'test2' %}" method="GET">
    {% for field in result_form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.first_name }} {{ field.second_name }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="test">
  </form>
```

I want to be able to use any attribute which person has:
`{{ field.first_name }}` 
`{{ field.second_name }}` 
or even
`{{ field.company.address }}`

Comment: I think you need someting like `persons = request.POST.getlist('persons[]')` (and name the text fields accordingly)

Comment: So I will have to bound data manually in templates?

Comment: @Peter your answer is a) wrong and b) has nothing to do with the question. For a start, Django does not use the Rails/PHP `field[]` convention.

Comment: @STX_user3581226 I'm not sure what the actual question is though. What exactly goes wrong with this, and what is `custom_data` supposed to be?

Comment: @Daniel yes, it does, see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1130 . I posted it as a comment because the question is not very clear to me and I just wanted to point TS in a possibly right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to have the data near the input in the template, you can add attributes to the filed like so:

You can define them as a part of the form class like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    example = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"placeholder": "This will go in the placeholder attribute of the input element."}))
```

You can also do it in the **init** method like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['example'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = "This will go in the placeholder attribute of the input element."
```

Comment: I know this method, however it is not so good if I want to keep relation, and pass variables like `field.company.address`, `field.company.name`. In that case each variable have to by pass explicite and manualy.

Comment: Then why don't you pass it as a context variable in the view?